# Convert Comma separated ids into its assigned values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am writing a view for the Data export feature ,So basically they need view all the columns with data associated to it.

I have a column in a table Languages Spoken and we are storing values as comma separated list  1,2,3 ....etc.,

where as 1 is english , 2 germany ,3 Spanish etc. this value is stored in different table.

```
StaffID       LanguagesSpoken
----------      -------------
1               1,2,3
2               3,4
3               2,5
```

So when we want to view the the expected out should be

```
StaffID       LanguagesSpoken
----------      -------------
1               English, Germany, Spanish
2               Spanish,Hindi
3               Germany,Arabic
```

Comment: Fix your data model.  Storing numbers as strings is bad.  Storing multiple values in a column is bad.  Not declaring foreign key references is bad.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am with you .. this has been done by previous developers

Comment: @forpas SQL Server 2017

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a table containing the languages like this:

```
CREATE TABLE languages (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO languages
  (id, name)
VALUES
  ('1', 'English'),
  ('2', 'Germany'),
  ('3', 'Spanish'),
  ('4', 'Hindi'),
  ('5', 'Arabic');
```

you can join the tables, group by StaffID and use [`string_agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select
  t.StaffID, 
  string_agg(l.name, ',') within group (order by l.id) LanguagesSpoken
from tablename t inner join languages l
on concat(',', t.languagesspoken, ',') like concat('%,', l.id, ',%')
group by t.StaffID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=73880e6b894e867ae55b2cffb2e3c657).
Results:

```
> StaffID | LanguagesSpoken        
> ------: | :----------------------
>       1 | English,Germany,Spanish
>       2 | Spanish,Hindi          
>       3 | Germany,Arabic
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to split the LanguagesSpoken string, do a join with Language table and use string_agg to get what you want. As mentioned by others your schema design needs to be fixed so this will help you get the data into the new schema also:

```
SELECT StaffID, value
FROM StaffLanguagesSpoken
CROSS APPLY string_split(LanguagesSpoken, ",")
```